# My reply to a tweet doesn't appear below the original tweet when it's expanded

Tags: twitter

I reply to somebody's tweets, (clicking the reply link below the original tweet), then when this tweet is expanded I see replies from other people who posted before and after me but not mine.

My account isn't private I use it since 2009 and I never spam.
And there's a bigger problem, always the same people's replies is listed below original tweets. There's some particular people, no matter when and how they reply, their replies are always listed below the original tweet and they aren't followed by the person the reply to.

I'm talking about a popular person in twitter so he gets many replies to his tweets but always the same person's replies is listed below his tweets, our replies are disappearing and only one reply is listed and it's always the sane person's reply. And the tweeter doesn't follow that person. What does this person do to get his replies being listed in the expanded tweet? Using a special application or hack software? How can I make my replies listed.

I use Firefox and Windows XP.

Comment: Post a link to your tweet

Comment: There's too many tweets like that, it's an account of a celebrity that I'm fan of. When he tweets I send reply, but it doesn't appear in the expanded tweet but other people's tweets are appearing and always the same people's tweets appear. So they have the chance to reach the celebrity while our tweets are disappearing among tens of tweets and the person may not read our tweets, it creates injustice.

Comment: Did your reply tweet contain a link? If so, this could be why it's not showing up (see [Why can't I see my own tweets under discover?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44600/why-cant-i-see-my-own-tweets-under-discover/44605#44605))

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the tweets that are listed (in case of the ones of celebrities) doesn't have any particular order.

Taking [this](https://twitter.com/justinbieber/status/325060182864453632) tweet as an example I think notice that most tweets that are listed either are:

1. Having a huge conversation related with them i.e many other users reply to that tweet and it's a talk(which may be off topic).
2. Have been retweeted (not always the case).
3. User who tweeted has many followers.

These were the general trends I observed in this tweet. The listing by Twitter in most cases might be in fact completely random (no concrete way of knowing).