# Why can't I see my own tweets under "discover"

Tags: twitter

I thought Twitter was a platform designed to focus on topics where users can easily participate in using hashtags.

I placed a hashtag in my first couple of tweets, and when I click it to show the list, I cannot find my tweet in there, even if I switch from `top` to `all` tweets.

Is there some kind of requirement to see it, like a minimum amount of followers? I've checked that `tweet privacy` is **unchecked** under account settings. I've gone through the faq as well but I can't find anything of use.

Comment: @batpigandme no problem, I edited it into my question

Comment: Tweets with links in them seem not to show up in discussion or search - check out [Search not returning tweets with a url](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8699)

Comment: @batpigandme wow, seriously? That kinda sucks. But I get that it probably helps preventing spam etc...

Comment: @MDeShaepmeester agreed that it definitely has major drawbacks, and it looks like you're certainly not alone in your frustration!

Comment: @batpigandme I can certainly believe that, the "small voices" are always left out like that.

Comment: Added this discussion as an answer just in case others run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tweets with hashtags thus far have all also contained links. They aren't showing up due to the omission/filtering out of tweets containing links/urls from Twitter discussions or in Twitter's search. Though this is not an 'official' rule, it seems to be a well documented problem (See [Search not returning tweets with a URL](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8699))

Twitter's FAQ suggests that this is part of an attempt to *combat spam and increase relevance* [Why are the tweets I'm looking for not in Twitter Search?](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#8650)

> Our search service is not meant to be an exhaustive archive of public
>   tweets and not all tweets are indexed or returned. Some results are
>   refined to better combat spam and increase relevance.