# How to contact someone from Twitter support

Tags: twitter

I tried to contact Twitter support but they sent me an automated generic reply. I need to contact a real person; do you know any mail address of somebody from the staff? Or somewhere where I can reach a real person? (Twitter help pages don't help.)

My problem is described here: [My reply to a tweet doesn't appear below the original tweet when it's expanded](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42699/my-reply-to-a-tweet-doesnt-appear-below-the-original-tweet-when-its-expanded)

Comment: To get support from Twitter (or any other company), it is first necessary to become a customer. In Twitter's case, the customers are advertisers. Open an ad account and spend enough money for Twitter to consider you a worthwhile customer, and you will get support. If you don't pay anything, you won't get much support.

Answer (score 3):

You could contact Twitter Support via Twitter at [@Support](http://twitter.com/support). [This page](https://support.twitter.com/forms) has all the information you need for contacting Twitter

Comment: It's not possible to reach them though @support they have too many followers and they get too many mentions from too many people who need help, my message would get unnoticed.

Comment: In which case, the second limk I provided shows how to contact Twitter directly depending on your case

Comment: I already contacted with the second link and that's from where they kept sending me automatically generated messages and not real responses. I want a real reply from a real person.

Comment: @Ece sorry to say this, but good luck. Contacting Twitter directly for technical support is difficult.