# Twitter reply not showing

Tags: twitter

I wrote a reply https://twitter.com/sxfjkl/status/1340050437131694083 to a message https://twitter.com/pamcakers/status/1340001830999384065 however when I try to view it along with the other replies to that message, it does not show up, even if I tell it to "Show more replies" and "Show additional replies". Why isn't it showing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine and I open your tweet, and I see the parent tweet.
[image]

But on opening the users tweet indeed it can't be seen. It can be on a variety of factors. I answered a similar question 7 years back. [Have a look](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42699/my-reply-to-a-tweet-doesnt-appear-below-the-original-tweet-when-its-expanded?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, you have described the issue I'm having, that my reply does not show when using the link to the parent of the reply. I looked at your older question but I did not see described any factors that may cause this behavior. The factors listed in its answer seem to describe different factors that influence the order of replies, but in my issue, the question is not about the sorting, but about whether the reply shows at all.